# Dummy coding from a Bayesian point of view

Tags: categorical-data, markov-chain-montecarlo, jags, bugs

If we want to use categorical variables in regression context, we are allowed
to use dummy codings such as [these schemes](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm).

Is this also required in a Bayesian (MCMC) context, such as with WinBUGS/OpenBUGS,
that we have to model k factors with k-1 dummy variables – or are we allowed to use k dummy variables and linear dependency of the variables is not an issue?

Comment: Bayesian or non-bayesian is not an issue here. If you fit your regression using maximum likelihood or Bayesian estimation wouldn't affect how you code the dummy variables...

Comment: Bayesian regression with Normal priors on the regression coefficients corresponds to Ridge regression, which adds a penalty to the original regression objective. For penalized regression, there are strong arguments to use k not k-1 dummy variables, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/440126/do-we-use-different-number-of-dummy-variables-for-classical-and-bayesian-stats) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231285/dropping-one-of-the-columns-when-using-one-hot-encoding/329281#329281)